# Decreases Clause for Expression Evaluation

Tags: dafny

I cannot seem to figure out why the following fails to establish termination;

```dafny
datatype Expr = Const(nat) | Add(Expr,Expr)

function eval(e: Expr) : nat
decreases e {
    match e
        case Const(v) => v
        case Add(e1,e2) => evalAdd(e1,e2)
}

function evalAdd(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) : nat
decreases e1,e2 {
    var n1 := eval(e1);
    var n2 := eval(e2);
    n1 + n2
}
```

I am aware that there are several ways I could prove termination here:

1. Inlining `evalAdd()` into `eval()` solves the problem.  However, this is part of a larger example where I want to split out functionality rather than have a single large `match` statement.
2. Defining a notion of `height(Expr)` also solves the problem.  However, to my mind, this should not be necessary.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
datatype Expr = Const(nat) | Add(Expr,Expr)

function eval(e: Expr) : nat
decreases e,1 {
    match e
        case Const(v) => v
        case Add(e1,e2) => evalAdd(e1,e2)
}

function evalAdd(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) : nat
decreases Add(e1,e2),0 {
    var n1 := eval(e1);
    var n2 := eval(e2);
    n1 + n2
}
```

The rule of decreases clauses for mutually recursive functions is that *every* call to another function in the mutually recursive bunch must have a callee-decreases clause less than the caller-decreases clause. So it helps to make all the decreases clauses "similar". Your original clause for `evalAdd` was `e1, e2` which has two elements, but the clause for `eval` had only one. There's nothing wrong with that in principle, except that it means that when `evalAdd` calls `eval`, it must decrease, which it doesn't.

So first, I changed your clause for `evalAdd` to `Add(e1, e2)`, which fixes that problem. But then the call to `evalAdd` from `eval` has an error, since it also needs to decrease. There I use a trick to basically convince Dafny to allow it to do the inlining for you: use a constant 0/1 to allow a single "extra" call that leaves the first element of the clause the same.

Comment: Well, I never would have figured that out --- thanks!

Comment: And so `1` is decreasing to `0` hence why Dafny is happy?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: You can remove the ", 1" and just have `decreases e` and Dafny will be equally happy. This is because, when there are no elements, to compare lexicographically, Dafny inserts a "top" element that is greater to any other element. So you'd have implicitly `decreases e, Top`, so the decreases works as well.